# Upgrade from mktemp() to mkstemp()

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

[mktemp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#deprecated-functions-and-variables) is deprecated and not secure. So I try to upgrade it to mkstemp().

```
class TestUtils:
    @contextmanager
    def temp_dir(self):
        tmp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        try:
            yield tmp
        finally:
            shutil.rmtree(tmp)

    @contextmanager
    def temp_file(self):
        with self.temp_dir() as tmp:
            yield tempfile.mktemp(dir=tmp)
            
            
class CsvTest(PandasOnSparkTestCase, TestUtils):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=CsvTest.__name__)

    def tearDown(self):
        shutil.rmtree(self.tmp_dir, ignore_errors=True)
        
        
        
    @contextmanager
    def csv_file(self, csv):
        with self.temp_file() as tmp:
            with open(tmp, "w") as f:
                f.write(csv)
            yield tmp
```

When I change `yield tempfile.mktemp(dir=tmp)`to `yield tempfile.mkstemp(dir=tmp)` it returns a tuple.

And when I change it to `yield tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=tmp, delete=False)` I got TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _TemporaryFileWrapper

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp):

> `mkstemp()` returns a tuple containing an OS-level handle to an open file (as would be returned by `os.open()`) and the absolute pathname of that file, in that order.

`mktemp()` just returns the pathname. So if you want to be compatible with `mktemp`, use

```
yield tempfile.mktemp(dir=tmp)[1]
```

to return the pathname.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
yield tempfile.mktemp(dir=tmp)[1]
```